# Open multiple tabs of gnome-terminal, each trigger command with N seconds delay

Tags: linux, bash, tabs, terminal, sleep

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --working-directory=xxx/yyy/zzz --tab -e "command 1" --tab -e "command 2" --tab -e "command 3" --tab -e "command 4"
```

I need each of these tabs to trigger the command with few second delay so I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --working-directory=xxx/yyy/zzz --tab -e "command 1" --tab -e "sleep 2" -e "command 2" --tab -e "sleep 4" -e "command 3" --tab -e "sleep 6" -e "command 4"
```

To give them 2 seconds difference, but these are still being triggered at the same time, is there any way to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=xxx/yyy/zzz --tab -e "command 1" --tab -e "sh -c 'sleep 2; command 2'" --tab -e "sh -c 'sleep 4; command 3'" --tab -e "sh -c 'sleep 6; command 4'"
```